# Rcpp error: static assertion failed: cannot convert type to SEXP, why?

Tags: r, rcpp

### Error

I can't understand why I'm having this compilation error using Rcpp (version 1.0.2):

From file `/home/rmagno/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h`:

```
Line 523 static assertion failed: cannot convert type to SEXP
```

[image]

### Source of the error

I'm trying to wrap this C function [glfwSetKeyCallback](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga7e496507126f35ea72f01b2e6ef6d155) from the GLFW library.

And I know that the error is stemming somehow from the CPP source file below but I don't understand what I am doing wrong:

#### glfw_types.h

```c
#ifndef RCPP_GLFW_TYPES_H
#define RCPP_GLFW_TYPES_H

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210595/s4-object-with-a-pointer-to-a-c-struct

typedef Rcpp::XPtr<GLFWwindow, Rcpp::PreserveStorage, glfwDestroyWindow> GLFWwindow_ptr;

#endif
```

#### glfw_set_key_callback.cpp

```c
#include "glfw_types.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

namespace {
  std::unique_ptr<Rcpp::Function> key_callback_func_ptr;
}

void glfw_set_key_callback_wrapper(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int modes)
{
  (*key_callback_func_ptr)(window, key, scancode, action, modes);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void glfw_set_key_callback(GLFWwindow_ptr window, Rcpp::Function key_callback) {

  key_callback_func_ptr = std::make_unique<Rcpp::Function>(key_callback);
  glfwSetKeyCallback((GLFWwindow*)window, (GLFWkeyfun) glfw_set_key_callback_wrapper);

}
```

### EDIT

The source code below that compiles the function `glfw_destroy_window` and exports it as `glfwDestroyWindow` uses the type `GLFWwindow_ptr` and compiles and works from R just fine.

#### glfwDestroyWindow.cpp

```c
#include "glfw_types.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export("glfwDestroyWindow")]]
void glfw_destroy_window(GLFWwindow_ptr window) {
  glfwDestroyWindow((GLFWwindow*)window);
  R_ClearExternalPtr(window);
}
```

### EDIT 2

This function also works fine:

```c
#include "glfw_types.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export("glfwCreateWindow")]]
GLFWwindow_ptr glfw_create_window(int width, int height, std::string title) {
  const char *title_c = title.c_str();
  return GLFWwindow_ptr(glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title_c, NULL, NULL), true);
}
```

### EDIT 3

This seems to be working...

#### The new glfw_set_key_callback.cpp

```c
#include "glfw_types.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

namespace {
  std::unique_ptr<Rcpp::Function> key_callback_func_ptr;
}

void glfw_set_key_callback_wrapper(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int modes)
{
  (*key_callback_func_ptr)(GLFWwindow_ptr(window, true), key, scancode, action, modes);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void glfw_set_key_callback(GLFWwindow_ptr window, Rcpp::Function key_callback) {

  key_callback_func_ptr = std::make_unique<Rcpp::Function>(key_callback);
  glfwSetKeyCallback((GLFWwindow*)window, (GLFWkeyfun) glfw_set_key_callback_wrapper);

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: My quick guess is that Rcpp is telling you that `GLFWwindow_ptr` is not a type it can translate for you.

Comment: But I have that typedef in the header file.

Comment: I think I suggested on you first question five days ago that you are up on a somewhat involved mission and need to study the available documentation, eg in our vignettes.  I can only repeat this and add to also: study some packages that do this.  It takes (a lot) more than a `typedef`.

Comment: With all due respect @Dirk, I got your msg the first time but I find it unfair. I have read all your vignettes, I've seen a youtube video of yours talking about Rcpp. I have looked at numerous packages on github using Rcpp. Now, on this topic, I have another function `glfw_destroy_window` that uses `GLFWwindow_ptr` successfully. I will post it as well, just in case it helps clarify my point.

Comment: Does your final edit mean that your problem is solved? then it would make sense to post this as a (self-)answer.

Comment: Hi Ralf, I am not entirely sure yet. I am getting a seg fault that might be related to this code.

Comment: If I change `GLFWwindow_ptr(window, true)` from the snippet "new glfw_set_key_callback.cpp" to `GLFWwindow_ptr(window, false)`, i.e. `finalizeOnExit` is `false`, will that mean that the Rcpp::XPtr instance won't be freed, ever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
#include "glfw_types.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

namespace {
  std::unique_ptr<Rcpp::Function> key_callback_func_ptr;
}

void glfw_set_key_callback_wrapper(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int modes)
{
  (*key_callback_func_ptr)(GLFWwindow_ptr(window, false), key, scancode, action, modes);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void glfw_set_key_callback(GLFWwindow_ptr window, Rcpp::Function key_callback) {

  key_callback_func_ptr = std::make_unique<Rcpp::Function>(key_callback);
  glfwSetKeyCallback((GLFWwindow*)window, (GLFWkeyfun) glfw_set_key_callback_wrapper);

}
```